# How to know the real amount of RAM in a VPS

Tags: memory, vps, xen

I've been told that a VPS's RAM can be manipulated (oversold) by VPS providers. I know I can always buy a VPS from a reputable company, but, really, how can one make sure the allocated memory is the one we have paid for. I am particularly interested to know this in respect with systems virtualized by Xen.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a meaningful question.  Do you mean "*how can I be sure that my VPS provider hasn't oversold the memory in their hosting server, and that I can call on all my allocated memory at any time and guarantee to get it*"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a technical problem.  It is a problem of business relationships, and as such not (to my mind) particularly on-topic for ServerFault.

From inside a host you generally have no way of seeing what the hosting server is doing - that's the whole point of a VPS.  Even if the hosting technology provided such a conduit, **they control the hosting server** so you cannot guarantee that the data that come down that conduit are valid.

If you want to be sure that your VPS provider isn't overselling core memory, then you need them to contractually guarantee it, ensuring that the contract gives you some way of validating that they're meeting their contractual obligations.  In practice, if being sure that you control the underlying resources is that important to you, it may well be cheaper to colocate your own physical box.